# Angular 2 - Rxjs Intelligent with VS 2015 update 3

Tags: visual-studio, angular, rxjs5

I am learning the Angular 2.

I am following exactly the tutorial Tour of Heroes (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/), I have everything work just fine.

Just one thing, it looks like the VS 2015 (with update 3) doesn't recognize extension functions from the Rxjs, can you advise how to fix it?

[image]

I have all imported as in the tutorial

```js
// Observable class extensions
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

// Observable operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

a note while checking the file rxjs/add/operator/debounce.d.ts
the observable founder is not found, in fact the folder is there
[image]

Comment: In `debounce.d.ts` can you please set path `'../Observable'` except `'../../Observable'`

Comment: I did tried as your comment, the issue still there. If the path is set to just '../Observable', it apparently got a wrong path

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import {Subject, Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Comment: that will work but you'll be loading the entire rxjs lib which is huge.

Comment: @vidalsasoon how s?